# How does a service communicate with an activity?

Tags: android, android-service

I want to create an application where i need to implement the concept of service. The service concept should be worked out from my activity.

Can anyone help out?

Thanks,

Niki

Comment: You should accept some answers, else you won't get much help from others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your service shall only be manipulated and accessed in your own application, implement simply a local service (See 5. in the [Service class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)).

You can then directly call the service functions from the activity.

If your service is meant to be available publicly, it is a bit more complicated. You'll need an AIDL interface. You can download the Music application source code that includes a service to play audio files in the background and can be controlled by any application. The control is done using Broadcast messages (see [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)).

Comment: I would like to see a sample code with output to know more in detail than from developer.android site. Can you pls help?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample has source code included. Simply try it in Eclipse and play with it.

Comment: Shows an error like'IllegalArgumentException'. I would just like to see the output of that code.